# Filtering by lightswitch fields

Tags: craft3, templating, search, filter, lightswitch

Bit of an unusual one and sure must be missing something but know if we have a defined lightswitch field we want to filter against it can quite easily be done so like this:

```
{{ craft.products().myField(1) }}
```

However, if I have several lightswitch fields and a front-end filtering form I don't especially want to explicitly do this against all of them, eg `{{ craft.products().myField(1).anotherField(9) }}`. Was wondering then if it is possible to build out some kind of dynamic search or filter but unless doing something crazy looks like the Craft search parameter won't filter against lightswitch fields, eg the following won't work:

```
{{ craft.products().search('myField:1') }}
```

I think I have found a workaround using the `where()` parameter but feels a bit … inelegant … as essentially specifying my query now against DB values rather than against Craft elements/properties:

```
{{ craft.products().where('field_myField=1') }}
```

Any thoughts on improving? Is there a way to do this in native Craft/twig without having to query against specific database values?

Cheers,

Cole

PS above are examples working with Craft Commerce Products. Not entirely sure if this is an issue limited to products as opposed to - say - entries but as these are both essentially elements had assumed not.

Comment: Searching against lightswitch should work. Did you tick _Use this field’s values as search keywords_ on your fields?

Comment: Bingo - I had updated the fields to be searchable but hadn't refreshed the search index. `php craft resave/products --update-search-index` has resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Glad you're sorted :)

Comment: Someone want to add an official answer for this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching against lightswitch should work. Make sure *Use this field’s values as search keywords* is checked in Settings → Fields → **your field** then run `./craft resave/entries --update-search-index` to (re)index your values.